# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when inserting element into linked list

Tags: c

I am new to data structures and I am trying to implement a linked list data structure. I am getting a "segmentation fault (core dumped)" during run time.

I am using a Linux terminal to compile and run the program. I have written a `insert_element()` function to insert a node at the beginning and a recursive function `print()` to print the list. I am getting the segmentation fault during run time. How can i get rid of it?

```
struct node{
        int data;
        struct node* link;
};

struct node* insert_element(struct node* A,int ino)
{
        struct node *temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp->data=ino;
        temp->link=NULL;
        if(A=NULL)
        {
        A=temp;
        }
        else
        {
                struct node* temp1=A;
                while(temp1->link!=NULL)
                {
                        temp1=temp1->link;
                }
                temp1->link=temp;
        }
        return A;
}

void print(struct node* ptr)
{
        if(ptr==NULL)
                return;
        printf("%d",ptr->data);
        print(ptr->link);
}

int main()
{
        struct node* head=NULL;
        head=insert_element(head,5);
        head=insert_element(head,5);
        head=insert_element(head,6);
        head=insert_element(head,3);
        head=insert_element(head,5);
        print(head);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your title refers to an "unknown type error". That can only happen in C as a compile-time error. If you had that error, your program wouldn't run and you couldn't get a segmentation fault.

Comment: @KeithThompson, When OP says "unknown type error" he is obviously not quoting an error message, but stating that he doesn't know what kind of error he is seeing

Comment: @jirassimok sir i am not getting any clue about -Wall and -Wextra you are talking about.. So plz tell me some more about it and thanks for your help..

Comment: @HAL9000: That was hardly obvious, but the title has now been edited so it doesn't matter.

Comment: @jirassimok i'am not understanding th concept behind your last comment if((char  * buffer == malloc(100)){ }else{ }. plzz explain...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiling your program with some helpful flags would have helped you solve your problem:

```
user@machine:~$ gcc -Wall -Werror -o scratch main.c
main.c: In function ‘insert_element’:
main.c:14:12: error: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Werror=parentheses]
         if(A=NULL)
            ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Without fixing this problem, you'll get

```
user@machine:~$ gcc -o scratch main.c
user@machine:~$ ./scratch 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

If we fix the error

```
if(A==NULL)
```

and change the `printf` statement

```
printf("%d\n",ptr->data);
```

we get this output

```
5
5
6
3
5
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a `A = NULL` where you should have a `A == NULL`. As it is now, you are setting `A` to `NULL`, then trying to access one of its fields.

In C, the assignment operator (`=`) returns the value it assigned. So when you say `if (A = NULL)`, it assigns the `NULL` to `A`, then returns `NULL`, so the condition is false and the `else` branch is executed.

```
else {
    struct node* temp1 = A; // now temp1 is also NULL
    while (temp1->link != NULL) // temp1 is NULL, so this is NULL->link
```

So you end up with `NULL->link`, which attempts to dereference `NULL`, which is an undefined behavior, and usually causes a segfault.

If you are compiling with `gcc`, I recommend using `-Wall` (and maybe even `-Wextra`) to display more compilation warnings, including a warning for using `=` in a conditional expression.

---

In case you're wondering why C allows this at all, it's very useful for checking the results of function calls. For example:

```
if ((char *buffer = malloc(100))) {
    // malloc worked, and you can use the buffer here
}
else {
    // malloc failed, so you can do something else
}
```